# Amitsur's theorem for generalized Severi–Brauer varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, motives, galois-cohomology, central-simple-algebras

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero and assume that $A$ is a central simple algebra of index $2^n > 2$. We denote by $\operatorname{SB}_i(A)$ the $i$-th (generalized) Severi–Brauer variety of $A$.

Consider the Galois cohomology ring mod $2$, denoted by $H^*(k, \mu_2)$.

We set $S_i := \ker(H^*(k, \mu_2) \rightarrow H^*(k(\operatorname{SB}_i(A)), \mu_2))$.

**Question**: What is $S_2$? Or even, what is $S_i$ for $i \neq 1$ ?

The case where $i = 1$ is solved (for any $p$) by a famous result of Amitsur, which states that $S_1$ is generated by the Brauer class of $A$, meaning that $S_1 = [A] \cup H^*(k, \mu_2)$ in our case.

I originally suspected that $S_2$ is surely zero, but that actually is not so clear to me now. The only thing that looks right, is that $S_1$ contains all $S_i$, since all $\operatorname{SB}_i(A)$ are known to become isotropic over $k(\operatorname{SB}(A))$.

**Edit**: Here are some new thoughts about this.

If one uses Lemma 6.5 from (*[Voevodsky - Motivic cohomology with $\mathbf Z/2$-coefficients](https://doi.org/10.1007/s10240-003-0010-6)*), one obtains (for  $\operatorname{SB}_i(A) = Y$ smooth, irreducible and $\mathcal{X}_Y$ the simplicial standard scheme of $Y$) that:

$$H^{n, n-1}_\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{X}_Y, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \simeq S_i \cap H_{et}^n(k, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}(n-1)).$$

We can identify:

$$H^{n, n-1}_\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{X}_Y, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \simeq \operatorname{CH}^{n-1}(X, n-2).$$

Let us assume that $\operatorname{ind}(A) = 4$.
Since the $i$-th Severi–Brauer naturally becomes isotropic over the generic point of the $i$-th Involution variety $Y_i:=I_i(D, \sigma)$, with $\sigma$ an orthogonal involution and $D$ Brauer-equivalent to $A$, we can focus on $Y_2$.

For our $A$, we find that $Y_2$ is a twisted form of the $D_2$-variety (we can choose $\operatorname{SO}_4$ as $D_2 = A_1 \times A_1$ for example) $D_2/P_2$.
This is just the first Severi–Brauer variety of a quaternion algebra $Q$.
Its Chow-Motive (with integer or mod-$2$ coefficients) is irreducible by some result of Karpenko and its Chow-Ring over $k$ (since $Q$ is not split) is thus just the fundamental class i.e. is zero.
Thus $h \in \operatorname{CH}^1(\overline{X})$ is not $k$-rational, which means that $Q$ is in $S_2$.

If we pick $n = 3$, we have
$H^{3, 2}_\mathcal{M}(\mathcal{X}_Y, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}) \simeq \operatorname{CH}^{2}(Y, 1)$.

I know nearly nothing about higher Chow groups, but I suspect that if $n$ is bigger than the dimension of $X$, then $\operatorname{CH}^n(X, *)$ is always zero, right?
So, for $\operatorname{ind}(A) = 4$, $S_2 \cap H_\text{ét}^n(k, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}(n-1))$ should always be zero, except for the $n = 2$ case.

If one writes $A = Q_1 + Q_2$, maybe the $Q$ from above is one of these two.
I mean the fundamental relations on the $D_2 \simeq SO(D,\sigma)$ kinda imply this. This means one has to choose an orientation which of the two $D_2$-varieties are $Y$ and which one has Tits algebra $Q$.

But I am not sure if I added this motivic cohomology stuff up the right way, because we have arrived at a contradictionary result.
Either $Q$ is not zero, then $S_2$ should be $Q\cup H^*(k,\mu_2)$, or
$s_2 \cap H_\text{ét}^n(k, \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}(n-1))$ is always zero (also for $n = 2$).

Comment: TeX note: for upright text in math mode, there are sometimes pre-defined commands, like `\ker`; or, if there are not, you can use, e.g., `\operatorname{SB}`.  (There are other commands, like `\text` and `\mathrm`, with related effects, but `\operatorname` is appropriate when you have something that is semantically an operator.)  Aside from semantics and more consistent typesetting, e.g., SB$_i(A)$ `SB$_i(A)$` vs. $\operatorname{SB}_i(A)$ `$\operatorname{SB}_i(A)$`, this approach has the advantage that it can be used in displayed math.  I have edited accordingly.

Comment: $\mathrm{CH}^{i}(X,n)$ is about codimension $i$ cycles on a $\dim X + n$ dimensional space. So it vanishes for $i>\dim X + n$ but that’s all you get for free.

Comment: Can you please recall the definition of a generlized Severi-Brauer variety?

Comment: The $i$-th generalied Severi-Brauer variety is a twisted form of the Grassmannian of $i$-dimensional subspaces of a $(\deg A)$-dimensional vector space.  Its points are the right ideals of $A$ of "reduced dimension" $i$.  (E.g., the case $i = 1$ is the usual Severi-Brauer variety.)

Comment: Looking only at the $H^2$ part, meaning $S_i \cap H^2(k, \mu_2)$, the kernel is the subgroup generated by $[A^{\otimes i}]$ in the Brauer group (one reference for this is Cor. 2.7 in Merkurjev-Tignol, "The multipliers of similitudes and the Brauer group of homogeneous varieties" Crelle 1995 [link](https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.1995.461.13)

Comment: @ Skip, ah. So, if the class $A$ decomposes as quaternion algebras, it has period $2$ and thus $[A]^\otimes 2 = 1$. I will look into the reference.

Comment: @ Oli Gregory, Ok. This means in my example the higher Chow groups do in fact not necessarily vanish. Thats unfortunate, but on the other hand, the contradiction is now not existent anymore

Comment: For “usual” Chow groups, I once attended a colloquium of Karpenko on Chow groups of generalized Severi Brauer varieties.  You might check Karpenko’s articles.

Comment: What's a reference for $S_1$ being equal to the ideal generated by $[A]$? I agree this is true in degree $2$ (this is Amitsur's theorem) and if $[A]$ is a symbol (because then $SB(A)$ is the norm variety of $[A]$).